# return json string xml based in spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

How to return json string after hit url? i hit  url.../helloworld/testing.htm but i got this response Error 404 /WEB-INF/jsp/"null".jsp. I am using Spring MVC hibernate.using Autowired i got string but i want xml based. So where i did wrong.Please let me know how i do?

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

    import com.google.api.client.json.Json;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    public class HelloWorldController extends MultiActionController{

        //@RequestMapping(value="/gDirectory/get_user_names.htm" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String add(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                Gson test = new Gson();
                return test.toJson("null");

            }

            public ModelAndView delete(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","delete() method");

            }

            public ModelAndView update(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","update() method");

            }

            public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","list() method");

            }

            public  String testing(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {


                Gson test = new Gson();
                return test.toJson("null");


            }

    }
```

Comment: if you want xml on run time you need to make that in a jsp page.by setting the content type to xml.

Comment: Is it posible without jsp page?i am sending ajax call from html and after alert(response); i want that string? is it posible?

Comment: yes it can be possible ,send a xml string in response of that ajax call and show that  on that page.but i'm nt sure it will work properly or not

Comment: @Autowired IDomainManager domainManager; Sir i got response but i want to convert domainManager  into MVC-Dispacher-servlet.xml  <bean class="com.controller.HelloWorldController">
      <property name="domainManager" value="domainManager"/> but not working can you tell me how i do this?
      
   </bean>

Comment: Sorry but m unable to get what you are using .can you show some code for this ?

Comment: Sir i solved that problem.Thankx for help me